# Unable to restore backup in solr 4.10

Tags: solr, lucene, backup, restore

I tried backing up my collection using

`http://xxxx:8983/solr/collection1/replication?command=backup&name=myTestbackup&location=/opt/solrBackupFolder`

I was able to confirm that with `/replication?command=details&wt=xml`

```
<lst name="backup">
  <str name="startTime">xxx xxx xx xx:xx:xx UTC xxxx</str>
  <int name="fileCount">303</int>
  <str name="status">success</str>
  <str name="snapshotCompletedAt">xxx xxx xx xx:xx:xx UTC xxxx</str>
  <str name="snapshotName">myTestbackup</str>
</lst>
```

For testing I am removing all the existing documents with
`update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>` where i can see the `Num Docs:0` in solr
After confirming the number of documents are `0` then I am using

`http://xxxx:8983/solr/collection1/replication?command=restore&name=myTestbackup&core=collection1&location=/opt/solrBackupFolder`

To restore my backup but it shows the below as my response when i restore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

and `/replication?command=restorestatus` this gives me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/making-and-restoring-backups.html)(I am using this as there is nothing i found for 4.10 and backup works) says it should return a `restorestatus` but i never got it. Can someone help me if I am missing something?

Comment: Did files get created in `/opt/solrBackupFolder`? Does the Solr log show anything?

Comment: Yes the files for created in `/opt/solrBackupFolder`

Comment: Logs does not show any errors or info or anything. except for the request received for restore

Comment: Is there anything I am missing?